# Prototype Function call and bind

Tags: javascript, call, bind

Can someone explain logic behind

```
Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);
```

As I read 'bind' function give to function on which is called a context of object in which to executs.

But in this case bind receive function. So according to me this is not intuitive syntax.
If i have further

```
 myOtherFunction.call(this)
```

is call is still connected with context of forEach?

Comment: Perfect examples given here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach` is a method, bound to the context of an array. So you could easily iterate over an array like:

```
 [1,2,3].forEach(function(x){ console.log(x) })
```

This is equivalent to:

```
[].forEach.call([1,2,3],function(x){ console.log(x) })
```

So you are passing `[1,2,3]` as the current context (`this`) of your call into `forEach()`.

What `Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);` does is calling (`call`) the `bind` function with another function (`Array.prototype.forEach`) as its current context to a variable.

```
var forEach=Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);
```

means literally spoken: »If a function call on `forEach` is made, please call it like you would, if you were in the context of `Array.prototype.forEach`.«
It is a shortcut to `[].forEach.call(this,function)`

For further references see MDN on [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [Function.protoype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).